# AWS Lightsail with Liberty server TCP bind to public IP

Tags: networking, websphere-liberty, amazon-lightsail

Liberty server is not recognizing the static IP I've assigned to the instance when binding TCP ports and is instead binding to the private IP of the instance. How can I force Liberty to bind to the public IP? Host is set to * in server.xml.

Comment: What does ifconfig and netstat say about the listening port and what static IP you think liberty should listen on?

Comment: ipconfig and netstat are both showing the private IP of the Lightsail instance. I'm not seeing the static IP I created and attached to the instance.

Comment: Sounds like liberty is binding to all addresses/interfaces that are valid on the system.  You don't have a liberty problem if the OS doesn't think your public static IP is valid.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help thus far. I've never set up a webserver in Lightsail before and this is all quite confusing. How can I ensure the OS thinks the static IP is valid?

Comment: No clue, but network software like websphere can only listen on interfaces that are actually available in the OS. Maybe you were supposed to manually configure the static IP?